Does the Firestore client instance need to be closed explicitly?
I have an application which uses Firestore and is hosted on Cloud Run.
I have a global variable which holds the client instance, and my question is whether it needs to be closed explicitly, since the Close method itself states "Close need not be called at program exit."?
The "config" package which holds the Firebase instances:
var App *firebase.App
var Firestore 

func LoadFirebase(ctx context.Context) {
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Firebase initialisation failed:", err)
    }

    firestore, err := app.Firestore(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Firestore initialisation failed:", err)
    }

    App = app
    Firestore = firestore
}

The "main" package:
func init() {
    initialisers.LoadFirebase(context.Background())
}

func main() {
    // initialise server
    PORT := os.Getenv("PORT")
    router := http.NewServeMux()

    Routes(router)

    server := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":" + PORT,
        Handler: middleware.CheckAuth(router),
    }
    
    // IS THIS NECESSARY?
    defer config.Firestore.Close()

    fmt.Println("Server is running on port:", PORT)
    log.Fatalln("Error starting server:", server.ListenAndServe())
}


No, it is not necessary. The documentation says that the application does not need to call Close() when the program exits. The program exits when the main() function returns.

The close method effectively terminates the client by shutting down the socket it maintains to transfer data with the server and stopping it from reconnecting automatically.  (This behavior is consistent between all Firestore client libraries, as far as I'm aware, and not unique to go.)  If that's not the behavior you require, then there is no need to call it.  The need to do so is entirely up to the requirements of your code.
